# Data from oracle db to sharepoint 2013 list

Tags: list, web-services, external-data, oracle

I want to get data from oracle to sharepoint 2013 list.I need one way sync only i-e from oracle to sharepoint list.Is there any way other than BCS or BDC? can i do this using web services and jquery and html but without using Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how much data we are talking about and what server access you might have.

- [Recommended] Use [Sharepoint CSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
- Web API without Visual Studio is difficult and not recommended.
- You can create a web service using Java.
- There are also a lot of proprietary solutions out there but remember you have to deploy oracle drivers on the server that interfaces with the database and don't expect those solutions to make things simpler.